# Swift 4 - How to update progressView in loop

Tags: ios, swift

I have created this progressView:

```
progress = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
progress.center = view.center
progress.setProgress(0.5, animated: true)
view.addSubview(progress)
```

In my viewDidLoad method, I call getLandGradingImages and inside that I do a loop, inside that I call getLandGradingImage for each result in getLandGradingImages, what would be the best way to update the progressView I created during this entire process:

```
getLandGradingImages(jobNo: jobNo) { result in
    //Define axis variables
    var x = 25
    var y = 80

    //Define image counter variable
    var counterImages = 0
    var actualImageCounter = 0

    //For each Lot Image
    for item in result
    {
        self.getLandGradingImage(image: item["imageBytes"] as! String) { data in
            //Create Image from Data
            let image = UIImage(data: data)

            //Add Image to Image View
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

            //Set Image View Frame
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 100, height: 100)

            //Define UITapGestureRecognizer
            let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))

            //Enable user interaction
            imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

            //Assign tap gesture to image view
            imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

            //Add Image to view
            self.view.addSubview(imageView)

            //Increase x axis
            x = x + 115

            //Increase image counter
            counterImages = counterImages + 1

            actualImageCounter = actualImageCounter + 1

            //If image counter is equal to 3, create new line.
            if(counterImages == 3)
            {
                //Increase y axis
                y = y + 115

                //Reset x axis
                x = 25

                //Reset image counter
                counterImages = 0
            }

            if(actualImageCounter == result.count)
            {
                //self.stopIndicator()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are those two methods I am calling in this process:

```
func getLandGradingImages(jobNo:String, completionHandler:@escaping (_ result:Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>) -> Void) {
    //Define array for returning data
    var returnedResults = Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>()

    //Call API
    WebService().GetLandGradingImages(jobNo: jobNo)
    {
        (result: Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //Return our results
            returnedResults = result
            completionHandler(returnedResults)
        }
    }
}

func getLandGradingImage(image:String, completionHandler:@escaping (_ result:Data) -> Void) {
    //Define array for returning data
    var returnedResults = Data()

    //Call API
    WebService().GetLandGradingImage(image: image)
    {
        (result: Data) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //Return our results
            returnedResults = result
            completionHandler(returnedResults)
        }
    }
}
```

For these calls, I am using Alamofire:

```
func GetLandGradingImage(image: String, completion: @escaping (_ result: Data) -> Void)
{
    let imagePath : String = image
    let url = URL(string: webserviceImages + imagePath)!

    Alamofire.request(url).authenticate(user: self.appDelegate.username!, password: self.appDelegate.password!).responseData { response in
        let noData = Data()

        if(response.error == nil)
        {
            if let data = response.data {
                completion(data)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            completion(noData)
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
var counter:Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            let fractionalProgress = Float(counter) / 100.0
            let animated = counter != 0

            progress.setProgress(fractionalProgress, animated: animated)
        }
    }
```

and inside the for loop:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    sleep(1)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.counter = self.counter + 1
                    }
                }
```

Still nothing, my the progress view appears but does not get updated.

Comment: Unrelated but please note that too many comments actually makes your code harder to read. Comments should be used to clarify non-obvious code. Adding a comment such as `//Create Image from Data` before the line `let image = UIImage(data: data)` doesn't tell the reader anything that isn't already 100% clear from the line of code.

Comment: @user770 In my viewDidLoad method, I call getLandGradingImages and inside that I do a loop, inside that I call getLandGradingImage for each result in getLandGradingImages

Comment: @user770 Updated my question.

Comment: When updating `counter` you need to take in consideration the total number of images in order to correctly set the progress, with your current code and if you only have 2 images, your progress will be at 0.02, which is almost invisible.